# How can I detect if iPhone screen is locked (off)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I would like to detect the status of the iPhone, such as if the screen is off (screen locked), or if the device has sound turned off.
Can an API do this, or is there any other way can do it?

Thanks vikingosegundo for helping me to edit the article,but the above is not what i want to know.
in my app, ijust want to check the device, i want to know if the iphone is sound off,and if the device is powered off(has no power). how can i know this ?

Comment: You're asking how to write a program to determine if the device it's executing on is turned off?

Comment: I assume you mean to detect if the phone is being turned off, not that it is actually turned off?

Comment: Many people call the iPhone Screen Lock button the on/off button.  Of course, when you lock the screen the screen is off but the phone is not.  Perhaps that is what Lee meant.

Comment: It is physically impossible to figure out if the iphone has no power. What would power your app?

Answer (score 5):

When the user locks the screen, `applicationWillResignActive` is called, and the app enters the "Inactive" state. Unless your app is running tasks that continue in that state (e.g. continuing to play audio) after about 20 seconds the phone will enter a sleep mode where your app is moved from inactive to its background state.

Comment: I don't know if this was true in 2011 but this is no longer true now. The applicationWillResignActive method is called a number of times. For example... when you swipe down the notification centre from top of phone, when an alert message pops up (such as a permission alert) and when the home button is pressed once.